# Testing for connection using capacitors

Tags: capacitor, inductor, measurement

I work in a common mode choke coil manufacturing company.  They often measure the insulation resistance as well as the connectivity of the coils. I have a good understanding of how insulation resistance is measured, but the measurement of connectivity of the wires stumps me.

The reason is, connectivity is measured in picofarads and it is named "IR contact limit" which is usually in the range of 50 pF value. If the wires are cut, the value drops lower to 20 pF. I have also noticed that the measurement probe for connectivity has a film capacitor attached to it which confuses me more.

I can only work out that the capacitors are charged and then it discharges into the coiled wires to measure the connections. The charge is then picked up by the meter to show the capacitance value in pF.

Is my understanding correct or is there a better explanation to how capacitors are used to measure connections in inductors?

Comment: Why don't you ask someone in your company to explain the methodology? Maybe you did; if so, what did they say? Maybe there's a schematic of the set-up you can find and post? Maybe the meters/displays used in the test-rig might yield a clue? Maybe you are assuming that what you describe is common-practice (it isn't as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 1):

There is a small capacitance (sometimes called a distributed capacitance) between the coils of an inductor. By using a capacitance probe and an ac signal the effective capacitance of the inductor can be measured. Improper winding can cause this measurement to be out of spec. If there is a break, then a capacitance appears at the break in series with the distributed capacitance thus lowering the overall measurement. In your case from 50pF to 20 p. Of course a coil resistance test will also identify the break.